# XmlWriter large xml file creation divided into methods

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlwriter

I am creating a large xml file using XmlWriter, and I know that using

```
             using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("file.xml", settings))
        {

            writer.WriteStartElement("Research", "http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "rixmldt", null, "http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML-datatypes");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xsi", "schemaLocation", null, "http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML");
            //dropdown selection for reseach id?
            writer.WriteAttributeString("researchID", "BOGUS ID");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("language", "eng");
            //fix date time
            writer.WriteAttributeString("createdDateTime", System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("xmlns", "xsi", null, "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Product");
            //dropdown selection for prioduct id?
            writer.WriteAttributeString("productID", "asdf");
            //status info
            writer.WriteStartElement("StatusInfo");

            writer.WriteAttributeString("currentStatusIndicatior", "Yes");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("statusDateTime", System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString());
            writer.WriteAttributeString("statusType", "Published");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.WriteStartElement("Source");
            writer.WriteStartElement("Organization");
            //organization info
            writer.WriteAttributeString("type", "SellSideFirm");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("primaryIndicatior", "Yes");
            //organization1
            writer.WriteStartElement("OrganizationID");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("idType", "Bloomberg");
            writer.WriteString("1234");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            //org 2
            writer.WriteStartElement("OrganizationID");
            writer.WriteAttributeString("idType", "FactSet");
            writer.WriteString("rep_example");
            writer.WriteEndElement();
....
            writer.WriteEndElement();
            writer.Flush();
}
```

Is regarded as the fastest way to produce a large file, but I can't seem to find anyone talking about (or in the XmlWriter docs) splitting it all up in to methods that generate chunks of xml. My method is around 150 lines, and I'd like to keep this as modular as possible since all of the data that's being populated will be mostly pulled in from a form. This means the method this statement is in will end up having tons of arguments as well.

So is something like this possible without using a filestream or saving the data locally, for the sake of modularity/ organization? Or would it just end up slowing it down?

Comment: Having methods for different parts doesn't make much difference. That single line doesn't give much information how you're actually writing things nor how you would split them.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen I added a large chunk (not all) of whats happening inside that line. Theres some areas like the organizations I could use a loop for of course, but I'm just trying to gauge my options

Comment: You can easily chop those into methods and just give the writer as argument if you want. It won't make it any slower and if it's clearer it's a good change.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen thanks, this is exactly what I wanted to hear :)

Answer (score 1):

I like the code below a little better than your because it is better organized, easier to read, and you don't have to add end elements

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            XmlWriterSettings settings = new XmlWriterSettings();
            settings.Indent = true;

            string header = "<Research xmlns=\"http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML\"" +
                                              " xmlns:rixmldt=\"http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML-datatypes\"" +
                                              " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.rixml.org/2013/2/RIXML\"" +
                                              " researchID=\"BOGUS ID\"" +
                                              " language=\"eng\"" +
                                              " createdDateTime=\"" + System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString() + "\"" +
                                              " xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\">";


            using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create(FILENAME, settings))
            {
                writer.WriteRaw(header) ;

                XElement product = new XElement("Product", new XAttribute("productID", "asdf"));

                XElement statusInfo = new XElement("StatusInfo", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("currentStatusIndicatior", "Yes"),
                        new XAttribute("statusDateTime", System.DateTime.Now.Date.ToString()),
                        new XAttribute("statusType", "Published")
                });
                product.Add(statusInfo);

                XElement source = new XElement("Source", new object[] {
                    new XElement("Organization", new object[] {
                        new XAttribute("type", "SellSideFirm"),
                        new XAttribute("primaryIndicatior", "Yes"),
                        new XElement("OrganizationID", new object[] {
                            new XAttribute("idType", "Bloomberg"),
                            "1234"
                        })
                    })
                });
                product.Add(source);

                XElement organizationID = new XElement("OrganizationID", new object[] {
                    new XAttribute("idType", "FactSet"),
                    "rep_example"
                });
                product.Add(organizationID);

                product.WriteTo(writer);

                writer.Flush();
                writer.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```